# Elementary proof of Hölder´s inequality (by convexity)

Tags: analysis, inequality, proof-writing

I am trying to prove the Hölder inequality but following these steps

**1)** Let $f:(a,b)\to\mathbb R$ be double differentiable then $f$ is convex if and only if $\;\;f''(x)>0$ for all $x\in (a,b)$

**2)** Let $a,b>0$ and  $0<t<1$. Show that $\displaystyle a^{1-t}b^t \ge(1-t)a+tb$

**3)** Use the above exercise to prove the  Hölder´s inequality. If  $x,y \in\mathbb{R}^n$ and $p,q>1 $ are such that: $\frac{1}{p}+\frac{1}{q} = 1$ then we have:

$$\displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^{n} |x^iy^i| \le \Big(\sum_{i=1}^{n} |x^i|^p\Big)^{1/p}\Big(\sum_{i=1}^{n} |x^i|^q\Big)^{1/q}$$

The first part I have it, for the second one the thing is to define the function $ t\mapsto a(b/a)^t$ then by the second derivative criterion we could show that is convex and we could have the above, but how can I define it (I was thinking in some of this sort $f(t)=a(b/a)^t$, but I think it won't work because $f(a) \not= a$)?.
And well the third part is not obvious to me, how could I have it with the above result?.

Thanks a lot for the help in advance :).

Answer (score 1):

Some hints:

For (2), take $-\log$ of both sides and use that $-\log$ is convex (by part (1)).

For (3), you have a typo (the final sum should involve $y$'s). The trick is to rearrange this so you can use the inequality in (2). Try doing the special case where $\sum_{i=1}^n |x^i|^p = 1$ and $\sum_{i=1}^n |y^i|^q = 1$ first.

Comment: thanks a lot for your help, but I have to do it using the functions and steps above :)

Comment: @user162343 Yes, these hints were for the steps you list. For example, for (2), prove that the inequality is true after taking $\log$ of both sides (then this implies what you want because $\log$ is increasing).

Comment: Well I hace tried yo do that hint and I got the expressioon for log of convexity  but I dont know how that helps :(